# Unable to load a trained checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following the code from here to learn the text summarization task with transformer model,  [It can be found here](https://github.com/rojagtap/abstractive_summarizer/blob/master/summarizer.ipynb)

But the code doesn't provide a way to load a model after training, so It's an inconvenience and I decided to write that function

Here is my code:

```
model = Transformer(
num_layers, 
d_model, 
num_heads, 
dff,
encoder_vocab_size, 
decoder_vocab_size, 
pe_input=max_len_news,
pe_target=max_len_summary,
)

model.load_weights('checkpoints/ckpt-5.data-00000-of-00001')
```

It throws an error:

```
ValueError: Unable to load weights saved in HDF5 format into a subclassed Model which has not created its variables yet. Call the Model first, then load the weights.
```

I'm totally new to machine learning and TensorFlow. I know what It's trying to say, but I just don't know how to fix this issue, please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call a model with dummy input before loading weights.

Try this:

```
model = Transformer(
num_layers, 
d_model, 
num_heads, 
dff,
encoder_vocab_size, 
decoder_vocab_size, 
pe_input=max_len_news,
pe_target=max_len_summary,
)

input = tf.random.uniform([1, 12], 0, 100, dtype=tf.int32) #create dummy input
enc_padding_mask, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask = create_masks(input, input) # create masks
a = model(input, input, enc_padding_mask, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask) # call the model before loading weights

model.load_weights('checkpoints/ckpt-5.data-00000-of-00001')
```

Comment: May you explain what variable "a" is doing in this code ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will give it a try

Comment: now It returns new error: TypeError: call() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'tar', 'enc_padding_mask', 'look_ahead_mask', and 'dec_padding_mask'

Comment: Andrey, may I ask whats does [8, 24] stand for in this situation ?

Comment: you can use any figures - because it is dummy input (the first - number of batches, the second - sequence length). 100 - is size of vocabulary

Comment: with that value you gave, It throws new error: InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [8,24,100] vs. [1,12,100] [Op:AddV2]

Comment: So I change it to fix the shape and the new error is:                                                                                  
    h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

    h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

    h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.open()

OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)

Comment: check that this file exists: 'checkpoints/ckpt-5.data-00000-of-00001'

Comment: create another question. This error doesn't relate to your question